# How to overwrite Referencing Parent Selector using Mixin in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

I had a common used component and its scss is like this:

```
.component {
    margin-right: 12px;

    &.specified-use-case {
        margin-right: 30px;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            margin-right: 70px
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want everything has same style in mobile view

```
.component {
    margin-right: 12px;

    // some predefined mixin
    @include viewport(mobile) {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }

    &.specified-use-case {
        margin-right: 30px;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            margin-right: 70px
        }
    }
}
```

But this can't change style for "specified-use-case" in mobile view. In order to do it I have to

```
.component {
    margin-right: 12px;

    // some predefined mixin
    @include viewport(mobile) {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }

    &.specified-use-case {
        margin-right: 30px;

        @include viewport(mobile) {
            margin-right: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 14px;
        }

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            margin-right: 70px

            @include viewport(mobile) {
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 14px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which just doesn't seem right to me. Is there a better way to define mobile view css just for once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CSS' specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (try [this calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)) you unfortunately need to repeat yourself. What your SCSS interpreter does is just compiling what you've written to standard CSS, which will look something akin to:

```
.component {
 margin-right:12px
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 .component {
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:14px
 }
}
.component.specified-use-case {
 margin-right:30px
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 .component.specified-use-case {
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:14px
 }
}
.component.specified-use-case:nth-child(odd) {
 margin-right:70px
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 .component.specified-use-case:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:14px
 }
}
```

As you can see, you're overriding each class with a `@media` ruleset just after it has been declared. And since I'm a big proponent to never use `!important` (because you'll open a pandoras box), the only way you can shorten your SCSS is doing:

```
.component {
    margin-right: 12px;

    // some predefined mixin
    @include viewport(mobile) {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;  // only need to define margin-bottom once, here.
    }

    &.specified-use-case {
        margin-right: 30px;

        @include viewport(mobile) {
            margin-right: 0px;
            //margin-bottom: 14px;, remove this
        }

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            margin-right: 70px

            @include viewport(mobile) {
                margin-right: 0px;
                //margin-bottom: 14px;, remove this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the rules inside of the media query:

```
@include viewport(mobile) {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;

    &.specified-use-case {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still can't prevent from repeating same code, and I need another selector for pseudo class nth-child

Answer (score 1):

seems like sass is wrong because you specify margins above a breakpoint, try this:

```
.component {
    margin-right: 12px;

&.specified-use-case {
    margin-right: 30px;

    &:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: 70px
    }
  }
 // some predefined mixin
@include viewport(mobile) {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
}
```